# MXNet Gluon - programmatically accessing neural net layer dimensions?

Tags: python, neural-network, mxnet

Let's begin by creating a very basic deep neural network in MXNet Gluon (inspired by [this tutorial](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter04_convolutional-neural-networks/cnn-gluon.html)):

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import gluon

ctx = mx.cpu()

net = gluon.nn.Sequential()
with net.name_scope():
    net.add(gluon.nn.Conv2D(channels=20, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
    net.add(gluon.nn.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
```

Now, if we want to print out the dimensions of a layer, all we have to do is...

```
print(net[0])
  # prints: Conv2D(None -> 20, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), Activation(relu))

print(net[1])
  # prints: MaxPool2D(size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=(0, 0), ceil_mode=False)
```

However, instead of printing it out, what if we want to *programmatically* inspect the `padding` of `net[1]`?

- When I try `net[1].padding`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'MaxPool2D' object has no attribute 'padding'`.
- When I try `net[1]['padding']`, I get the error `TypeError: 'MaxPool2D' object is not subscriptable`.

So, what's the right way to programmatically access the dimensions of a neural network layer in MXNet Gluon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(net[1]._kwargs["pad"])`

Try getting them from kwargs dictionary. Look for other keys at [this source](https://beta.mxnet.io/_modules/mxnet/gluon/nn/conv_layers.html#Conv2D).

[This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mU0JfZEh26AwWGDKEbl9f7pgzqpmL9je) is the Colab link for the code.

Other keys are `kernel` for kernel size, `stride` for stride, .

For getting all the keys and values:

```
for k, v in net[1]._kwargs.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: 1. In the printout in my question, it's `padding`. So, why is it `_kwargs["pad"]` and not `_kwargs["padding"]`?

Comment: 2. What's the right way to see all the items that are in the dictionary? (e.g. pad, stride, ...)

Comment: 1. That was my reaction, too. But, they programmed it this way. The exact code is `if self._kwargs['pad'] != (0,) * len_kernel_size:
            s += ', padding={pad}'`.

Comment: 2. Here's what I came up with... `list( net[1]._kwargs.keys() )`

Comment: For 2 I have updated my answer. `dict.items()` offers a nice interface for looping through keys and values.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a lot for your help!!